# Bitcoin Core Node Stops Continuously

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

I've recently setup a Raspberry Pi 4 to run as a Bitcoin Core node. I've noticed that after starting Bitcoin Core is shuts down after a short period of time. My first thought was that the Pi was going to sleep so I installed xscreensaver to prevent the Pi from going to sleep. This did not solve the problem. I also read about memory potentially being an issue but the Pi has 8GB of memory so I can't imagine this is the problem. Here are the details about my set up.

Raspberry Pi 4 8BG
External SSD 1TB
Internet 500Mbps

After starting Bitcoin Core I run getblockchaininfo using bitcoin-cli and have found that my block count moves up then stops. Here are the steps at each successive restart.

359388, 438037, 443757, 444235, 444610, 444834

As you can see I get a few hundred block in most cases and then bitcoind stops. Why is bitcoind stopping and how do I get it to stay active?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any logs in `bitcoind`'s `debug.log` (in its data directory, not sure of its location on raspiblitz).

Comment: I was able to determine the issue. The external SSD auto mount did not work properly so the drive was not seen by bitcoind. Now that I've updated the mount directory of the SSD all is working as expected.